# Spring MVC: Using @Autowire is getting references to different spring bean instances

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a UserCredetnialsDatSourceAdapter defined in my Spring app context file. I also have a custom filter added to the Spring via the DelegatingFilterProxy.

This filter is using the @Autowire to get a reference to the DataSource Bean.  I also @Autowire the DataSource in my DAO. When I debug I see different instance id's to the datasource in the Filter and DAO instances.  Why are there 2 instances whenthese are singletons by default?

I also fired up jvisualvm and I looked at the heap and all my beans in my app context have 2 instances? Thanks for any insight maybe the bean pre/post processing has something do with it or maybe I should not be using @Autowire in a Filter. Any help is apprciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-context.xml,/WEB-INF/config-context.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

Interesting I think I see what it going on. There are 2 instances because there are 2 contexts. One for the app and 1 for each request (Thread) I assume?  Is there a way to specfiy which context to use?  Maybe filter is not the answer and I will need to use AOP. Need to research how to inject a bean in @Aspect, if that is even possible.

Thanks!!

-Joe

Comment: Can you post your web.xml file? To check that your are not building two different application contexts that use the same configuration file.

Comment: Is your application context getting instantiated twice, once by web.xml and once in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing your `/WEB-INF/config-context.xml` as part of your Root Application Context(one loaded up by `ContextLoaderListener`) as well as your Web Context(loaded by `DispatcherServlet`). You can probably remove it from the one for `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Thanks to Luciano and GriffyDog for the quick responses that led me to the answer and to Biju for the explanition.